# How to use the reflexive verb « se ressentir »

Tags: usage

> Ne touchez pas à quoi que ce soit dans ce labo. Ça pourrait **se ressentir sur** mes résultats.

The use of « se ressentir » here pulled me up short, as I would have expressed the same idea with a different construction:

> Ne touchez pas à quoi que ce soit dans ce labo. Mes résultats pourraient **s’en ressentir**.

When « se ressentir » is used to mean "X has an unfavourable effect on Y" or "X takes its toll on Y", I wonder if both versions are equally acceptable? The thing is, this is the first time I have seen the first construction.

Answer (score 1):

La deuxième phrase est de très loin préférable.

Dans la première 'se ressentir sur' semble être / est utilisé avec le sens de influencer, modifier, retentir sur mes résultats. Cela me semble être maladroit.
Il s'agit, peut-être, d'un glissement (pas très heureux, à mon avis ) de l'emploi de 'se ressentir'.

Answer (score 0):

Je suis d'accord avec Annie Chabot. La première phrase peut s'entendre, mais ce n'est pas du "bon" Français, elle est au mieux familière. La deuxième est correcte. On pourrait dire aussi (mais cela sort un peu du cadre de votre question):

> Ne touchez pas à quoi que ce soit dans ce labo. Mes résultats pourraient être affectés.